# javascript onclick and iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Programming newbie here.  I've written a game that generates a random spread of cards and the user highlights those that match a given Boolean phrase (e.g. "black or face card").  They then click a submit button to find out if they are correct or not.  I want to allow them to select or deselect cards before submitting.  Here's that part of the code:

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
          x.setAttribute("src", deck[randomNumber].location);
          x.setAttribute("alt", deck[randomNumber].name);
          x.style.margin = "0.5%";
          x.style.border = "5px solid transparent";
          x.style.borderRadius = "10px";
          document.body.appendChild(x);
          x.onclick = function() {
            if (this.style.border === "5px solid gold")     
            {this.style.borderColor = "transparent";
             var index = answers.indexOf(this.alt);
             answers.splice(index, 1);
            } else {this.style.border = "5px solid gold";
            this.style.borderRadius = "10px";
            answers.push(this.alt);                    
            }
```

It works fine on my laptop.  On iPhone and iPad though, while I can tap to highlight the card, I can't remove the highlighting.  Tapping on a highlighted card does nothing.

I've seen a number of posts on here that talk about onclick on iOS but they seemed not applicable to my specific situation and/or over my head.

Thank you.